# java.lang.NullPointerException at ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have two layouts, one has editText and the other has a listview to change the editText's Fonts.

The app is getting crushed at clicking the button for opening the layout with listView probably because of the array Adapters.

Please help me.

Every Button is working fine. Just the btnChangeFont button is problematic.

My Code:

```
MainActivity.java[enter image description here][1]
package com.example.xarn.test;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    String[] values = new String[]{

            "art_science",
            "big_bold",
            "bold_itallic",
            "crazy_days",
            "gabriola",
            "handwritting",
            "new_bold",
            "new_itallic",
            "oldschool",
            "rough&tough",
            "sketch",

    };

    ListView listView;
    EditText text;
    LinearLayout choosefonts;
    ImageButton btnOpen, btnClose, btnNew, btnSave, btnDelete,btnChangeFont;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
        listView =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        btnChangeFont = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnChangeFont);
        btnChangeFont.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.choosefonts);
                choosefonts = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.choosefonts);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,values);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    switch (position){
                        case 0:text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/art_science.ttf"));
                             break;
                        case 1: text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/big_bold.ttf"));
                            break;
                        case 3:text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/bold_itallic.ttf"));
                            break;
                        case 4:text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/crazy_days.ttf"));
                            break;
                        case 5:text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/gabriola.ttf"));
                            break;
                        case 6:text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/handwritting.ttf"));
                            break;
                        case 7:text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/new_bold.ttf"));
                            break;
                        case 8:text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/new_itallic.ttf"));
                            break;
                        case 9:text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/oldschool.ttf"));
                            break;
                        case 10:text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/rough&tough.ttf"));
                            break;
                        case 11:text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/sketch.ttf"));
                            break;}
                }
            });

            }
        });


        text.setHint("Write Your Note Here............");
        text.setTextIsSelectable(true);

        btnSave = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog d = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                d.setTitle("Save As");
                d.setContentView(R.layout.dialogsave);
                d.show();
                Button btnDialogSave = (Button)d.findViewById(R.id.btnDialogSave);
                btnDialogSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        EditText saveText = (EditText)d.findViewById(R.id.SaveText);
                        try {
                            File myFile = new File("/sdcard/"+saveText.getText()+".txt");
                            myFile.createNewFile();
                            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter =
                                    new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                            myOutWriter.append(text.getText());
                            myOutWriter.close();
                            fOut.close();
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                    ""+saveText.getText()+" Saved",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        d.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        btnNew = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnNew);
        btnNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                text.setText("");
            }
        });
        btnClose = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
        btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        btnOpen = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnOpen);
        btnOpen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final Dialog d2 = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                d2.setTitle("Open");
                d2.setContentView(R.layout.dialogopen);
                d2.show();
                Button btnDialogOpen = (Button)d2.findViewById(R.id.btnDialogOpen);
                btnDialogOpen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        EditText openText = (EditText)d2.findViewById(R.id.OpenText);
                        try {
                            File myFile = new File("/sdcard/"+openText.getText()+".txt");
                            FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                            BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(fIn));
                            String aDataRow = "";
                            String aBuffer = "";
                            while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
                                aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";
                            }
                            text.setText(aBuffer);
                            myReader.close();
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                    ""+openText.getText()+" Opened",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
            d2.dismiss();

                    }

                });

            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

            return true;
        } else if(id == R.id.changeFont){
           final Dialog d3 = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            d3.setContentView(R.layout.choosefonts);
            d3.setTitle("Choose Fonts");
            d3.show();
          /*  String[] values = new String[]{
                    "art_science",
                    "big_bold",
                    "bold_itallic",
                    "crazy_days",
                    "gabriola",
                    "handwritting",
                    "new_bold",
                    "new_itallic",
                    "oldschool",
                    "rough&tough",
                    "sketch",

            };
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,values);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    switch (position){case 0:text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/art_science.ttf"));
                        // text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/art_science.ttf"));
                        break;
                        case 1: text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/big_bold.ttf"));
                            break;
                        case 3:text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/bold_itallic.ttf"));
                            break;
                        case 4:text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/crazy_days.ttf"));
                            break;
                        case 5:text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/gabriola.ttf"));
                            break;
                        case 6:text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/handwritting.ttf"));
                            break;
                        case 7:text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/new_bold.ttf"));
                            break;
                        case 8:text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/new_itallic.ttf"));
                            break;
                        case 9:text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/oldschool.ttf"));
                            break;
                        case 10:text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/rough&tough.ttf"));
                            break;
                        case 11:text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/sketch.ttf"));
                            break;}
                }
            });*/
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

xml code for layout 1:

```
<RelativeLayout 

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:height="200pt"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnNew"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/new1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnNew"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnNew"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnNew"
        android:background="@drawable/save"
        android:clickable="true" />


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnOpen"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnSave"
        android:background="@drawable/open4"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnClose"
        android:background="@drawable/close"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnOpen"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnOpen" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        android:background="@drawable/delete"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnClose"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnClose" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnChangeFont"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnDelete"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnDelete"
        android:background="@drawable/star"/>


<RelativeLayout/>
```

logcat error

```
06-22 11:48:18.188    8058-8058/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.xarn.test, PID: 8058
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.xarn.test.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:65)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4443)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18442)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you add your logcat error please

Comment: Specifically look for the line number where it crashed

Comment: in my case I dnt get wht is pointing to null.. am a newbie in android studio but had java classes for 2 years. in netbeans

Comment: Logcat will be helpfull, also check if all variable and objects was instantiated. If don't know much about, read post suggest for azurefrog.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you forgot to assign your EditText view called "text" to the matching view in your xml layout.

Comment: it is assigned.. yet I dnt know what is the error. I think its bcus of arrayadapter. wn I put ArrayAdapter<String>(this,blah,blah,blah) its shows red in color. wn I replace it wd MainActivity.this. app crashes.       i also think MainActivity is not linked properly with the other layout which contains listview. but cant figure out how

Answer (score 0):

The variable `text` is defined, however, it is never assigned a value.

Comment: it is assigned.. yet I dnt know what is the error. I think its bcus of arrayadapter. wn I put ArrayAdapter<String>(this,blah,blah,blah) its shows red in color. wn I replace it wd MainActivity.this. app crashes.

Comment: i also think MainActivity is not linked properly with the other layout which contains listview. but cant figure out how